# Autenticação básica em API Rest (C#)

Tags: c#, api, rest, autenticação

Tenho uma aplicação feita em ASP.MVC em que implementei o ASP.NET Identity para o registo/login de utilizadores.

Agora tenho que criar uma Web API Rest com uma simples autenticação, só um único utilizador e uma unica password.

Alguém poderá dar umas dicas como implementar essa autenticação básica na Web API?

Obrigado

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Vc tem que adicionar ao header HTTP o seguinte campo

```
Authorization: Basic QWxhZGRpbjpPcGVuU2VzYW1l
```

onde QWxhZGRpbjpPcGVuU2VzYW1l é o usuário e senha codificados em Base64.

Saiba que a segurança da sua senha é zero. Qualquer um pode clicar com o botão direito no browser e ver os headers... a senha vai estar lá codificada em base64, e qqer um pode decodificar isso...

Enfim... boa sorte ;)

Comment: Boas TTKDroid, Agradeço a sua resposta. Era uma boa forma de fazer se a segurança da senha não fosse zero.. Não há outra forma mais segura?Obrigado

Comment: Tudo depende de como funciona o seu backend. Se ele trabalha com autenticação Basic, ou Digest ou mesmo Oauth2... se vc está construindo o backend, procure por JWT (JSON Web Token). Eu particularmente recomendo a utilização de tokens, mas obviamente quanto mais elaborado e seguro maior o custo de implementação e teste.

Comment: Obrigado TTKDroid, vou fazer uma pesquisa sobre o que vc disse.

Comment: Valeu Miguel... se vc acha q a sua pergunta foi respondida clica lá.